# How to write CSS code without using :not selector?

Tags: html, css, internet-explorer-8, css-selectors

I have an article page that I am making small CSS changes, such as margin and font size, to. My code has to be able to be supported by Internet Explorer 8 and above. The problem is, I am using some CSS selectors that IE8 does not support. How do I write my CSS code without using the :not selector?

**HTML for sample article page**

```
<div class="entry">
  <h3 class="social-title>Share This Article </h3> 
  <div class="social-content>
    <table>
      <td><a href="twitter.com"><img class="" src="twitter.png"><span class="">Twitter</span></a></td>
      <td><a href="facebook.com"><img class="" src="facebook.png"><span class="">Twitter</span></a></td>
    </table>
  </div>

<!-- The article would start here -->
  <p class="category_row"><h1 class="category-title>Lifestyle</h1></p>
  <p style="margin: 0in 0in 0.0001pt; line-height: 13.5pt; vertical-align: baseline;"><a href="example.com/article.html"><img alt="" style="float: left;" src="example.jpg"></a>Article goes starts here...</p>
  <p style="margin: 0in 0in 0.0001pt; line-height: 13.5pt; vertical-align: baseline;">Second paragraph</p>
  Third paragraph
</div>
```

**CSS I am using**

```
.entry p:not(.category_row) {
font-size: 14px;
line-height:22px;
}

img (margin: 10px)
```

So far example, if I wanted to add margin to the image that is in the article section, how would I write the CSS code so that it only affects the image in the article section and not the images in the `<div class="social-content">`? Without using :not?

Also how would I write CSS code to change the font-size of the article to a font size of 14px and line height of 22px? Without affecting everything else above (not in the article section) ?

Sorry if this is confusing, but I will clarify more if need be!

Comment: Are you against using some javascript to fill in support?  If not...  Then your solution is selectivizr.js - http://selectivizr.com/

Comment: No javascript here. Because of certain limitations to the code I can access, I am only able to use CSS.

Comment: Outside of doing it by giving those certain paragraphs a class and increasing specificity there is no other dynamic solution without using :not.  So it's either don't support IE or stick a javascript library in there...

Comment: Your HTML seems rather malformed. Several of your attribute values have unmatched quotes, and a `p` cannot contain an `h1`. Some of these errors can actually interfere with your selectors, so you need  to make sure that your HTML is valid first and foremost.

Comment: ewww...inline styles...you could style the `p` tags like you want, then use `!important` on `.category_row` to make sure those styles appear as you'd like.

Comment: @BoltClock sometimes that would be how the article is put in as, so I have to work around the errors. Lucky me. The code above is a sample HTML of an article.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You will need to be more verbose if you want to support older browsers. The joy of the newer syntaxes is we are able to be more pithy, but if you have IE 8 in your supported list of browsers, you'll need to start with styling more general selectors and then overriding those styles in more precise selectors.

```
.entry p {
   font-size: 14px;
   line-height:22px;
}

.entry p.category_row {
  font-size: XXpx;
  line-height:XXpx;
}
```

I don't know where your article section begins from your markup. Figure out what is the most logical container for image would be, and then constrain your selector with it. Note `article` is an HTML5 element, so you would be remiss not to use it:

```
<article>
  <img ... />
</article>
```

And article images would be styled with this simple selector: `article img { ... }`

If you want to use `article` with IE 8, be sure to include this: https://code.google.com/p/html5shiv/

Comment: Or he can choose not to use any of the new semantic elements, and not the shiv, and just stick with what IE8 does already support reasonably.

Comment: Probably for the best, as I see now that he says he can't fiddle with the Javascript at all :)

Comment: @ChrisHardie Thanks Chris. I hadn't thought about it this way, code but then target whatever is specified in the :not selector to go back to normal. Seems like this is the way that I'll have to do it!

Comment: @user3097331 It will be, until IE 10 becomes standard. Feel free to mark as the answer if this has helped at all :)

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you wrap the actual content in it's own `div`?

```
<p class="category-row">....</p>
<div class="post-content"><!--- maybe use article tag here -->
   <p>First paragraph....</p>
   <p>Second Paragraph</p>
</div>
```

Then you can just reference the p's like

```
.entry .post-content p {
     ....
}
```

Also, "category row" doesn't look like it should be a paragraph?
If it is a "row" a div or a span would be more appropriate.
If it contains nothing but the h1 you might as well scrap it and leave the h1 be there without a wrapper.

If you use the article tag (or any of the other new html5 semantic tags) include [html5shiv](https://code.google.com/p/html5shiv/), as Chris said in his answer.

Comment: I do not have access to the templates and there are thousands of articles across multiple portals that I would have to change. But thank you.

Comment: If you change the templates they will be changed too (unless you have a really weird caching solution going on).  
Without changing the HTML Markup at all, it is impossible to select the only the p tags unless you use some sort of more sophisticated CSS selecter like :not.

Comment: Since I am just an intern, I would not have access to those templates, even though it would save me so much time. I like the :not selector, but we still support IE 8. Boo.